# remove quotes from specific field - integer between quotes

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I want to remove quotes from specific field where there is an integer between quotes.

From this line : `"AAA","99"`

to this line :  `"AAA",99`

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
s='"AAA","99"'
sed 's/"\([0-9]*\)"/\1/g' <<< "$s"
"AAA",99
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
echo '"AAA","99"' | sed -E 's/"([0-9]+)"$/\1/'
```

Output:

```
"AAA",99
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /^"[0-9]+"$/ { gsub(/"/, "", $2) } 1'
```

That works as follows:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }  # Delimit output the same way as the input

$2 ~ /^"[0-9]+"$/ { # if the second field ($2) consists of only numbers encased
                    # by double quotes (i.e., matches the regex ^"[0-9]"$)
  gsub(/"/, "", $2) # remove the quotes from it
}
1                   # print in any case
```

To make this work for any (and not just a specific field), do the replacement in a loop:

```
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if($i ~ /^"[0-9]+"$/) { gsub(/"/, "", $i) } } 1'
```

The changed bit here is

```
{                              # Do this unconditionally in every line:
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {   # wade through all the fields
    if($i ~ /^"[0-9]+"$/) {    # then do with them the same thing as before.
      gsub(/"/, "", $i)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,what if i want this to be done for every column that have integer between quotes ? not just for the seconds column

Comment: Wade trough the fields, do the transformation for all. See the edit.