# How to extract number with awk in quotes after equal sign

Tags: awk, extract, quote

I have something like this in my parameters:

config_version = "1.2.3"

I am trying to get 1.2.3 without quotes with awk command, is it possible ?

how I get quoted number:
awk '/config_version =/ {print $3}'  params.txt
output: "1.2.3"

desired: 1.2.3

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828519/remove-quotes-from-specific-field-integer-between-quotes

Comment: An alternative method could be `grep 'config_version[[:space:]]*=' file | cut -d \" -f2`

Answer (score 2):

find the line with the right label, trim the quotes of the value and print.

```
$ awk '$1=="config_version"{gsub(/"/,"",$NF); print $NF}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

And also with `awk`:

```
$ echo 'config_version = "1.2.3"' | awk -F'=' '{gsub(/"/,"",$2);print $2}'
 1.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `gsub` to remove leading and trailing `"`s:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$3);print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory (or, perhaps "one of", rather than "the".  There are lots of ways to do this!) sed solution:

```
sed -n '/^config_version *= */{y/"/ /; s///p;}'
```

Note that this leaves a trailing space in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
echo 'config_version = "1.2.3"' | grep -Po 'config_version\s+=\s+"\K[^"]+'
1.2.3
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 0):

You might set `FS` so `"` would be treated as part of field seperator, let `file.txt` content be:

```
config_version = "1.2.3"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \"]+"}/config_version =/{print $3}'
```

output

```
1.2.3
```

Explanation: I instruced AWK to treaty any non-empty string consisting of spaces or `"` or combination thereof to be treated as field seperator. If you want to know more about `FS` and others I suggest reading [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk, you might also use a pattern with a capture group and print the group 1 value using `m[1]`

```
awk 'match($0, /config_version = "([^"]+)"/, m) {print m[1]}' file
```

If there should be digits optionally followed by a dot an digits:

```
awk 'match($0, /config_version = "([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)"/, m) {print m[1]}' file
```

Output

```
1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 ways to do it. the clean way like  (`\042` octal is double quote `"` )

```
{mawk 1/2 | gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "\042" } $1 ~ /config_version =$/ {print $2}'
```

I specify `$1 ~` in the offball chance that it's a phrase that shows up AFTER the version number, if data was misformatted. Another more extreme version of it asks FS to do all the work

```
{mawk 1/2 | gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "(^[ \t]*config_version =\042|\042.*$)" 

    } NF==3 {print $2}'
```

Here i let FS gobble up the rest of the record, from left to right, so NF==3 provides enforcement exactly only this scenario will show up. And finally, a purist approach

```
{mawk 1/2 | gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "(^[ \t]*config_version =\042|\042.*$)" ;

    OFS = "" ;} ( NF == 3 ) && ( $1 = $1 )'
```